# Show that cross product of a x b is perpendicular to b

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, cross-product

How do I know the cross product of A x B is perpendicular to B.
 I'm little confused because there are 3 vectors instead of 2.

```
A = (0, -2, 5)
B = (2, 2, -5)
C= ( 7, -4, -5)
```

On `R2` plane, `(a x b) * b = 0` proves that `a x b` is perpendicular to `b` , but how do I find that on `R3`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Hi ,this is linear algebra / computation matrix question hence, related to computer science.

Comment: But it's not a programming question (yet). As stated, it's a mathematics question.

Comment: Math questions belong on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Questions like this come down to precisely what you take to be your definitions.

For instance, one way to *define* the cross-product A x B is this:

1. By R^3 we mean three dimensional real space with a fixed orientation.
2. Observe that two linearly independent vectors A and B in R^3 span a plane, so every vector perpendicular to them lies on the (unique) line through the origin perpendicular to this plane.
3. Observe that for any positive magnitude, there are precisely two vectors along this line with that magnitude.
4. Observe that if we consider the ordered basis {A, B, C} of R^3, where C is one of the two vectors from the previous step, then one choice matches the orientation of R^3 and the other does not.
5. Define A x B as the vector C from the previous step for which {A, B, C} matches the orientation of R^3.

For instance, this is how the cross product is defined in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product):

> "The cross product a × b is defined as a vector c that is perpendicular (orthogonal) to both a and b, with a direction given by the right-hand rule and a magnitude equal to the area of the parallelogram that the vectors span."

If this is your definition, then there is literally nothing to prove, because the definition already has the word "perpendicular" in it.

---

Another definition might go like this:

1. By R^3 we mean three-dimensional real space with a fixed orientation.
2. For an ordered basis { e1, e2, e3 } of R^3 with the same orientation as R^3, we can write any two vectors A and B as A = a1 e1 + a2 e2 + a3 e3 and B as B = b1 e1 + b2 e2 + b3 e3.
3. Observe that, regardless of the choice of { e1, e2, e3 } we make in step 2, the vector C := (a2 b3 - b2 a3) e1 - (a1 b3 - b3 a1) e2 + (a1 b2 - b1 a2) e3 is always the same.
4. Take the vector C from the previous step as the definition of A x B.

This isn't a great definition, because step 3 is both a lot of work and complete black magic, but it's one you'll commonly see.  If this is your definition, the *best* way to prove that A x B is perpendicular to A and B would be to show that the other definition gives you the same vector as this one, and then the perpendicularity comes for free.

A more direct way would be to show that vectors with a dot product of zero are perpendicular, and then to calculate the dot product by doing a bunch of algebra.  This is, again, a fairly popular way to do it, but it's essentially worthless because it doesn't offer any insight into what's going on.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I think i needed to use this formula:    AB= BC=CA = 0

Answer (score 0):

SO, after some of Research I finally figured out how to prove the vectors are perpendicularly to each other on R3.

```
A= (a1, a2, a3)
B= (b1, b2, b3)
C= (c1, c2, c3)

(AB x AC )* AB = 0
(AB x AC )* AC = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand what the cross product does. It gives a vector orthogonal to the two vectors.

> The cross product a × b is defined as a vector c that is perpendicular
>   (orthogonal) to both a and b, with a direction given by the right-hand
>   rule and a magnitude equal to the area of the parallelogram that the
>   vectors span.

you can simply show this by using the definition of orthogonality which is from their dot products being zero.